# Suitecrm Elasticsearch Integration

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to integrate elsaicsearch with suitecrm.

I've followed the document as per https://docs.suitecrm.com/admin/administration-panel/search/elasticsearch/

Then I tried to run full indexing from suitecrm, I got "index_not_found_exception" hence created indexes manually in the elasticsearch.

After that also when I am trying to run the indexing, no logs showing in suitecrm or elasticsearch and search in elasticsearch is not working.

Suitecrm version

```
Version 7.12.5
Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344)
```

Elasticsearch version

```
    "number" : "7.17.5",
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get any suspicious logs in suitecrm.log so had enabled debug mode for the logs
https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/logging/

Then I clicked on full indexing I found below log line

`Elasticsearch trying to re-indexing a bean but this module is blacklisted: SchedulersJobs`

I followed this document then https://docs.suitecrm.com/blog/scheduler-jobs/

And lastly this step `Admin / Repairs / Quick Repair and Rebuild`

After that it started working